# Queries too long(1-3 seconds), show a loading process icon

Tags: android, window, loading

What should I do with long data processing?
When a new activity is opened we get a black screen for 3 seconds.
I need a way to properly handle this.

Comment: Are you loading any data from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask` to do the processing in the background and communicate the information back to the UI on completion. Quoting the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html),

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

There's a basic example of subclassing `AsyncTask` in the documentation.